# CSS3 - Android: translate3d(0, 0, 0) - force hardware acceleration

Tags: android, css, css-selectors, css-transforms

I recently was having a performance issue on an app I was developing for Android despite the hardwareAccelerated tag in the manifest being enabled.

Animations and general, dynamic style changes were taking for ages. E.g., the following snippet of code would take a second or two to display:

```
<script>
    var elem = popup;
    elem.style.display = 'block';
</script>

<style>
    #popup {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<div id="popup">1, 2, 3...</div>
```

I then uncovered a trick I had previously found in the past and forgotten about:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

This works great, but I am a little confused as to which class/element this applies to.

Previously, I had used the following:

```
* {
    -wekbit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Which worked fine, but on page, I had a scrolling UL, the UL would not render well after being scrolled, so after doing a bit of googling, I changed `* { ... }` to `body div { ... }` and this seems much more reliable.

So it begs the question, is there a particular selector the -webkit-transform is meant to be applied to, as a general rule? I thought it was the element being animated, in this instance `#popup`, but when I attempted that, no joy...

I hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I removed it as it caused weird behavior on small screens (smartphones / portrait). Parent selector, which had

```
.container > * {-webkit-translate3d(0,0,0)}
```

caused collapsing in nested elements. I spotted that only on small screens and I could find any decent solution.